# CSS z-index doesn't respond properly - submenu hidden underneath content

Tags: html, css, z-index

I created a header ribbon menu (horizontal menu on top of page), that when hovering on its links, a sub-menu opens for each of them, that should display on top of the main content.

The problem is the sub-menu gets rendered underneath the main-content.

I tried setting a higher value for the sub-menu `z-index`, but that didn't help.

When I set the main content's `z-index` to `-1` (`0` doesn't work either), the sub-menu shows up, but then all the buttons in the content doesn't work.

I search my entire CSS and there is not even one `z-index` assignment.

**Update**

The content div is styled:

```
#content {
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 176px;
  bottom: 25px;
  padding: 20px 0px 63px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: please post some css and/or html code, otherwise it's not possible to exactly determine the problem

Comment: I don't know what to paste in, I have hell of a lot CSS and HTML. What I can definitely say is that I've checked all my CSS, and `z-index` isn't set even once, I'm looking for hints that will help me determine the issue.

Comment: well at the very least the z-index and position of the involved divs, and the html order/hierarchy of the divs

Comment: 1) Can you please expand more on the position thing? 2) Well the menu is obviously preceding the content div.

Comment: @cppanda I updated my question with some CSS.

Comment: A [codepen](http://codepen.io/) with your your menu markup, a really basic container, and your menu and container css would be super helpful in resolving this. As TDsouza pointed out, running your html through the [validator](http://validator.w3.org/) can help uncover wierd issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If both your menu and #content blocks are absolutely positioned, you will need to set a positive z-index value on both of them to allow overlap (with your menu having a higher z-index than your content).

**CSS:**

```
#content {
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 176px;
  bottom: 25px;
  padding: 20px 0px 63px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#menu {
  z-index:10;
}
```

Comment: well, when i gave answer you haven't added your css! But as @lota have given solved your problem +1 to him!

Answer (score 0):

What position have you set to the hover element to?? z-index only works on positioned elements (position:absolute, position:relative, or position:fixed).

The issue may be in your HTML rather than your css, for e.g if you've forgotten to close an element, it may overlap others elements.

either way it would be great help if you added some code to your question.

Comment: Both are positioned, document validated. Issue still exists.

Answer (score -1):

Possible Errors:

1. Your Menu Container Div may have negative z-index.
2. Your Body or Wrapper may have a very large value of z-index.

Solution:

1. Remove All z-index and just copy the code of menu and paste at the end of body tag or wrapper div tag. You can also add z-index:99; to submenus.
2. Remove z-index from Body or Wrapper and add z-index to menu.

Comment: Well as I already said, I search all my CSSs and the `z-index` property isn't set even once, nor does it appear in the HTML as inline style.